# UserStore(IUserStore) is getting disposed when calling FromSql in ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have implemented IUserStore of asp.net identity in UserStore class .
I am using ef core and everything works fine when i am accessing any table using entity and dbcontext.

But when i am calling the FromSQL method to execute stored procedure then debug point goes directly to dispose of UserStore. And then it never come back to previous point.

I don't understand why FromSql disposing UserStore .

Same issue occurs when i tried it with Ado.net and open the connection.

Code : `_dbContext.Query<string>().FromSql($"{SqlConstants.ApiLogLevelCheck} @input_json_api", param);`

I expect it to return the result of stored proc but it goes to dispose of UserStore

Comment: I strongly suspect something is throwing an exception. The fact that you're not seeing one suggests that something in your general exception handling strategy isn't working well - it's *hiding* exceptions from you.

Comment: [Raw SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) returning primitive types are not yet supported, i.e. you can't use `Query<string>`. Create, register and use [query type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) representing the resulting record.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right , exception handling was not correct so i didn't get any exception . thanks

Comment: @IvanStoev yes , i will correct it and replaced it with primitve type . thanks